# When relating 3 entities in CRM 2011 using Advanced Find only 2 entities show up in edit columns

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm trying to create a view in CRM 2011 that will show a few columns from Customers (Account), Orders (SalesOrder), and Order Products (SalesOrderDetail). I already know I need to start at the child-most entity so under Advanced Find I select "Order Products" under Look for. When I do this I'm able to select columns from Orders but unable to select columns from Customers.

Is this even possible to accomplish in CRM?

I'm trying to create the following result set:

Account.Name,
Account.Email,
SalesOrder.OrderNumber,
SalesOrderDetail.NetAmount,
SalesOrderDetail.ShipDate

Comment: You cannot accomplish this from within CRM, but you might be able to do it by manually editing the fetchXML for the view.  When I have a minute I will try and produce your view using that method.

Answer (score 3):

I verified that you cannot manually add a second link within a view query.  To my knowledge it is also not possible to add these columns though javascript.  You can get the account name in your view simply by using the account lookup on the Order.  If you need for the account email to also be in the view, then I suggest you add this field to the order entity and populate it with post callout logic on the account.

Comment: Yeah, the email address field really made this an issue. I think I'll have to make a direct relationship between customer/orderdetail to make this work for like ad1ka said. Thanks again for the response!

Comment: I think duplicating the field on the order in a callout is the safer/cleaner method, but ad1ka suggestion of adding a direct relationship will certainly work.  You could hide this relationship and have similar callout logic to update the lookup on the order detail based on the lookup on the order.

Answer (score 1):

I Second Zach’s idea, but suggest adding a direct relationship between customer and orderdetail . This way you can use fetchxml to show account.email or any other account.* for that matter.
The downside is you’ll need to sync order.customer changes to orderdetail.customer.

The better option is to simply create a report and show that in an iframe or a webresource.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a direct relationship from customer to order detail as well but its a bit of extra work. Thanks for all the responses, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible even if we edit the fetch xml it wont work